# Hadoop - List all sub-directories in a HDFS directory and save each directory path into a bash variable

Tags: linux, bash, hadoop, awk, hdfs

Suppose I have a HDFS directory called `myDirectory` containing **variable number of subdirectories** as follows:

```
/tmp
     |___mainDirectory
            |___ subDirectory1
            |___ subDirectory2
            .
            .
            |___ subDirectoryN
```

How can I capture the path to each subDirectory within the mainDirectory as a bash variable?

For example, in the above case, I would end up with N bash variables whereby each variable would look something like:

```
var_1=/tmp/mainDirectory/subDirectory1
var_2=/tmp/mainDirectory/subDirectory2

..etc
```

So far, I have got till the point where I am awk-ing the column containing the directory paths after doing a `hadoop fs -ls /tmp/mainDirectory`

```
$hadoop fs -ls /tmp/mainDirectory | awk '{print $8}'
/tmp/mainDirectory/subDirectory1
/tmp/mainDirectory/subDirectory2
.
.
/tmp/mainDirectory/subDirectoryN
```

However, I am not able to capture the individual directory paths into separate bash variables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're bale to get the result:

```
$hadoop fs -ls /tmp/mainDirectory | awk '{print $8}'
/tmp/mainDirectory/subDirectory1
/tmp/mainDirectory/subDirectory2
.
.
/tmp/mainDirectory/subDirectoryN
```

You may use the command assign them to bash variables,

```
$ declare $(hadoop fs -ls /tmp/mainDirectory | awk '{print "var_"NR"="$8}')
```